# The format of the data in a cell of table - matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a table called `v` with three columns which the third column (i.e Edge column) is splitted to two columns that includes `Nan`. I need to check if the value in the third column is equal to `Nan` then I skip that line of table. The Problem is when I use `Nan   Nan` to check the value in the third colum I am not able to find it (i.e. it shows an error) and If I use only one `Nan`, it shows an error. Any idea how I can sort it out?
Thanks

The data format:

```
Event   Node     Edge
Snode    2     Nan   Nan
```

The actual table is in the follwing link:
http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.bfsearch.html

Comment: Is this an actual `table` variable in MATLAB, or this is some text file that you have stored somewhere?  Also please show us your code that illustrates what you have tried in your question.  You mentioned you've tried a few things but you haven't actually shown us.

Comment: This is a table. Actually I am using the bfsearch (http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/graph.bfsearch.html) which the result will be represented in a table. I am working on the resulted table to extract some information

Comment: could you provide that acutal table? from what it looks like there is a 1x2cell array in the 3rd column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 3 columns turn out to be a (X,2) matrix (check with `T.Edge`) so you need to address the values with `T.Edge(x,1)` and `T.Edge(x,2)`.

```
s = [1 1 1 2 3 3 3 4 6];
t = [2 4 5 5 6 7 4 1 4];
G = digraph(s,t);
plot(G)
T = bfsearch(G,1,'allevents');
disp(T);
X=(isnan(T.Edge(:,1)) & isnan(T.Edge(:,2)) ); %get all with both NaN
disp(T(~X,:)); %show the rest
```